# YouTube Data API - Statistics Refresh

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Do the statistics (and any other information) from the `YouTube Data API` only update at given intervals, e.g. once a day, once every 12 hours etc.

I can't seem to find any information about this in the documentation. I also know you can use `ETags` to check if the data has been modified, however knowing that the data only updates once a day, for example, would be useful.

---

I am using this endpoint:

```
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list
```

Comment: What do you mean by statistics? update of what? the channel numbers in YouTube? what kind of data? Can you please elaborate your question.

Comment: By statistics I refer to the view count, video count etc. that YouTube return from their API. If you look to the endpoint I included in the question, I am basically wondering is there a point when that data is updated regularly with the most recent view counts etc. or just updated in general!

Comment: If I am not wrong in understanding your problem, than you want a real time statistics of a given video, right?

Comment: Well it would be `channel` but yes that's essentially what I mean. What I have discovered so far is within maybe 12 hours of running the same call that statistics don't change. So i was wondering if there is a point in time they are updated, for example: once daily.

Comment: Although this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#Latency_Information) is in v2, it will give you an idea. Standard feeds are updated periodically, with the update frequency varying from feed to feed. Many feeds are updated every 30 to 40 minutes but other feeds such as those that capture daily, weekly or monthly results – may only be updated hourly or even daily. Check the link above for more information.
Just take note that if you want different metrics, then the [YouTube Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/) can help you with that.

Comment: Awesome thank you!